# split file into columns with awk

Tags: bash, file, awk, multiple-columns

I have a file which looks like this:

```
1. result = 1.2.3.4 (1.2.3.4)
   info: [Affected]

2. result = www.addr.com (2.3.4.5)
   info: [not Affected]
```

And now I want to split it in three columns, example:

```
1.2.3.4       1.2.3.4   Affected
www.addr.de   2.3.4.5   not Affected
```

I am using awk for that: `cat filename.txt | awk -F "[=()'']" '{print $2 $3 $4}'`

but I still not get three columns in a row. How can I fix it? the second question: is there a better alternative than awk?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can unset the record separator to read in each block separately, like this:

```
$ cat file
1. result = 1.2.3.4 (1.2.3.4)
   info: [Affected]

2. result = www.addr.com (2.3.4.5)
   info: [not Affected]
$ awk -F'[]=():[:space:][]+' -v RS= '{print $3, $4, $6 (NF==8?" " $7:"")}' file
1.2.3.4 1.2.3.4 Affected
www.addr.com 2.3.4.5 not Affected
```

The ternary at the end handles the two different numbers of fields (7 or 8, depending on "Affected" or "not Affected"). If there are 8 fields, then the seventh one is printed after a space, otherwise, nothing is printed.

To achieve a more neatly formatted output, you can use `printf` instead of `print`:

```
$ awk -F'[]=():[:space:][]+' -v RS= '{printf "%-12s%10s   %s%s%s", $3, $4, $6, (NF==8?" " $7:""), ORS}' file
1.2.3.4        1.2.3.4   Affected
www.addr.com   2.3.4.5   not Affected
```

The format specifiers dictate the width of each field. A `-` causes the content to be left-aligned. `ORS` is the Output Record Separator, which is a newline on your platform by default.

In terms of aligning the columns, it depends on whether you're looking for something human- or machine-readable. If you're looking to import this data into a spreadsheet, perhaps you could separate each column using a tab character `\t` (for example), which could be done by adding `-v OFS='\t'` to the first version of my answer.

Answer (score 3):

You need to read the section as a single record, you can do this in GAWK by using `RS=`(nothing). This reads blocks as records.

```
awk -vRS= -F"[)(=\n]+" '{print $2 $3 $4}' file

1.2.3.4 1.2.3.4   Affected
www.addr.com 2.3.4.5   not Affected
```

Comment: get following exception: awk: invalid -v option, and without "v" it works fine but it dosen't show the third column

Comment: @Loretta Are you using GNU awk? Try `-v RS="\n\n"`.

Comment: Sounds like you might not have GNU awk. If you don't there needs to be a space between `-v` and `RS`.

Comment: @TomFenech If I seperate -v Rs, I still don't get the third one

Comment: @Loretta Don't know if thats just a typo in your comment but `RS` needs to be uppercase.

Comment: @Loretta it works fine for me (although I get leading whitespace at the start of each line). Perhaps the input in your question is slightly different?

Comment: @TomFenech sry, I changed the output

Comment: wk -v RS= -F"[)(=\n[]" '{print $3 $4 $7}' file.txt I am using now this, but it still has the last "]" in it. (how can I change the space between the rows?)

Comment: @Loretta Use Tom's answer if you want better spacing :)

Comment: @User112638726 but what is if I want to say how large the space should be

Answer (score 1):

**Some more `awk`**

**Input**

```
$ cat file
1. result = 1.2.3.4 (1.2.3.4)
   Affected

2. result = www.addr.com (2.3.4.5)
   not Affected
```

**Output**

```
$ awk  's{print $0}s=/^[0-9]+\./{ gsub(/[()]/,"");printf ("%s %s", $4,$5);next}' file
1.2.3.4 1.2.3.4   Affected
www.addr.com 2.3.4.5   not Affected
```

**-- Edit -- for revised input**

```
$ cat file
1. result = 1.2.3.4 (1.2.3.4)
   info: [Affected]

2. result = www.addr.com (2.3.4.5)
   info: [not Affected]
```

**Output**

```
$ awk  '{gsub(/[()\[\]]/,"")}s{$1="";print $0}s=/^[0-9]+\./{printf ("%s %s", $4,$5);next}' file
1.2.3.4 1.2.3.4 Affected
www.addr.com 2.3.4.5 not Affected
```